# Kendo Grid: Column Template Click event throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list?

Tags: javascript, onclick, kendo-grid

I am having a kendo grid with a column template click event. But on clicking the cell it is throwing the following error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

following is my column template.

```
columns: [
    {
      field: 'name',
      title: 'Industry',
      headerTemplate: '<span>Industry</span><br><span style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 400;">2-digit Code</span>',
      width: '40%',
      template: '<div style="text-decoration: underline" onClick=\'logElement(#= name #)\'>#= name#</div>'
      //template: function (dataItem) {
      //  return '<span style="text-decoration: underline">' + dataItem.name + '</span>';
      //}
    }
```

Google search saying it may be syntax error, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_parenthesis_after_argument_list

But I could not found what I haven't escaped in the above template.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Don't use inline HTML attribute handlers - attach listeners properly using Javascript instead, and you'll avoid all your escaping problems.

Comment: In my case, I would like to have the click event on each cell of that particular column

Answer (score 1):

Google's right: It is a syntax error. You are trying to submit a name to the function `logElement`. Let me guess: `name` is a string? In this case you have to put the value into quotes. This should work:

```js
columns: [
  {
    field: 'name',
    title: 'Industry',
    headerTemplate: '<span>Industry</span><br><span style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 400;">2-digit Code</span>',
    width: '40%',
    template: '<div style="text-decoration: underline" onClick="logElement(\\"#= name #\\")">#= name#</div>'
    //template: function (dataItem) {
    //  return '<span style="text-decoration: underline">' + dataItem.name + '</span>';
    //}
  }
```

Comment: You have to provide a bit more details: Complete and reproducible code (ideally on something like jsbin.com) and the complete error message.